# I don't understand a passage that includes the line " “This puts the ball in the hands of the ‘national political parties’

Tags: sentence-meaning

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/trump-coronavirus-25th-amendment-happens-085144841.html), there are passages, reading,

> And whilst the 25th Amendment of the constitution sets out how a vice-president assumes power when a president is incapacitated - what happens when a presidential candidate becomes ill or withdraws is lesser known.

-->OK

> Should Mr Trump be unable to continue as the Republican nominee, New York University law professor Richard Piles told the Washington Post in May the Republican national committee would assume control.

-->Alright

> **“This puts the ball in the hands of the ‘national political parties’,** which for this purpose means the legal entities known as the Democratic and Republican national committees,” said the professor.

-->I'm sorry I'm not sure about this passage, after reading the latter, reading as,

> In this situation, an emergency Republican convention would be held where members from each state or territory vote on the new nominee - casting the same number of votes as they are entitled to at an ordinary convention.

So from the 2nd passage, should Trump be unable to act as the Republican nominee, the Republican national committee would assume control. But the passage in the question reads that "for this purpose" some entities including Democrats sounds like to be set. Yet, the latter passages says, "**In this situation, an emergency Republican convention would be held where members from each state or territory vote on the new nominee**"

So what role would the "some entities" including Democrats after all play? In what way am I reading wrongly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “This puts the ball in the hands of the ‘national political parties’, which for this purpose means the legal entities known as the Democratic and Republican national committees,” said the professor.

“put the ball in the hands of X” means that X is running the show now. This refers to how in most sports the person with the ball is the focus of the action and will determine what happens next, while everyone else can only watch and react.

“for this purpose” says he’s using the term “national political parties” to mean “the Democratic and Republican national committees” in this specific context, rather than other possible meanings due to US political parties’ odd internal legal structure not being widely known or understood.

Overall, the professor here is trying to state a general truth, that if *either* party’s nominee is incapacitated, that party’s national committee would determine what happens next. He isn’t limiting his statement to the specific case of Donald Trump this year; he is saying this is what would happen with any party in any year.